# In vim, how do you add files from the buffer list - that match a pattern - to the arguments list?

Tags: vim, vi

Say I had opened vim with no arguments, then from within vim opened 10 .txt
files and 10 .py files. Also, let's say the files are scattered around my file
system. The buffer list contains all 20 files.

Now I want to add the 10 .py files to the arguments list. I want to do
something like `:argadd *.py`, but this just creates a new file called '*.py'
and adds it to the arguments list.

I see from the help that argd[elete] can use a pattern, so I could delete all
the .py files with `:argd *.py`. Is there a way to do something similar for
`:arga[dd]`?

```
:[count]arga[dd] {name} ..
            Add the {name}s to the argument list.  

:argd[elete] {pattern} ..
            Delete files from the argument list that match the
            {pattern}s.
```

Surely there's a better way than navigating to each .py file and running
`:argadd`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can go through all your buffers and add them to the argument list based on some discriminant with a single easy command:

```
:bufdo if &ft == 'python' | argadd | endif
```

or, if you really don't like typing:

```
:bufdo if&ft=='python'|arga|en
```

See `:help :bufdo`.

Comment: For all the scorn it gets, one cool thing about vimscript is that it is not something you have to learn wholesale, either when you start out or when you have a plugin idea. Instead, it is something that you *eventually* introduce progressively into your workflow to solve more complex problems in smarter ways, one function at a time.

Comment: This thought came into my mind too when I was reading the answer, VimScript is nifty.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's sort of a "made up" question, I think. One rarely needs so many buffers/args at the same time that naive `:argadd #10 #12 #15 #20` would be totally impractical.

But if you insist you need this then I'd suggest to try expression register, sort of

```
:argadd <C-R>=join(expand("*.py",1,1))<CR>
```